# Unable to upload file in headless Chrome

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I use WebDriver 3.12.0 and ChromeDriver 2.40 with Chrome 67. I initialized driver variable as below:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(new ChromeOptions().setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs).addArguments("--start-maximized").setHeadless(true));
```

I get `TimeoutException` for this line, when I execute it in headless mode. It works fine when I execute it in normal mode.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(mainPage.labelForInputFileField));
```

Error message:

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed:
>   waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath:
>   //*[@id="formUpload"]/p[1]/label (tried for 30 second(s) with 500
>   MILLISECONDS interval)
>
> at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:80)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:265)
>   Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="formUpload"]/p[1]/label"}

Comment: error is because of //*[@id="formUpload"]/p[1]/label  , xpath . can you share the HTML code for the mentioned xpath. NoSuchElement can be raised beacuse of iframe. Check if there is any iframe involved.

Comment: @cruisepandey : Yes, there is iframe on that page. `<label class="forFileInput" for="fileUpA" multiple="">Choose a file!</label>` This field is inside a `<fieldset>`.

Answer (score 1):

As per your response, you will have to switch to the **frame** to interact with elements which are inside of it.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("frame id ")));
```

// your interaction with element inside the iframe

Then it is always a good practice to switch to **default content** once you are done with **iframe**.

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: This fieldset is not inside iframe. Iframe contains only two scripts.

Comment: The element you want to interact is in iframe, right ?

Comment: No, it is outside of iframe.

Comment: can you share the HTML code for the button which is outside of iframe ?

Comment: It is just a field, when clicked a file browser dialog is opened automatically. I shared it earlier: `<label class="forFileInput" for="fileUpA" multiple="">Choose a file!</label>`

Comment: well ,you can build an **xpath** like this : `//label[contains(text(),'Choose a file!') and @class='forFileInput' and @for='fileUpA']`

Comment: I get same error again: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for presence of element located by

Comment: can you print `System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.xpath(" //label[contains(text(),'Choose a file!') and @class='forFileInput' and @for='fileUpA']")).size());` I'm sure either it would return 0 , or more than 1

Comment: It is 0, but found problem. This site has HTTPS configured, but it is untrusted. It doesn't cause problem in normal mode, but maybe in headless. How could I ignore certificate errors in headless mode?

Comment: Since it is zero , even if you ignore certificate errors  ,I am afraid that would do the job.

Comment: I tried same with valid certificate and it is ok. So that is problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following Chrome options:

```
options.addArguments("--proxy-server='direct://'");
options.addArguments("--proxy-bypass-list=*");
```

it makes headless execution much faster.

[From this issue](https://github.com/Codeception/CodeceptJS/issues/561).

Comment: Problem here is, that it is unable to find UI elements in headless mode.

Comment: I had a similar issue. In headless mode, every wait condition would timeout (or take like 5 times longer than in normal mode). With these options, the elements would load faster and selenium would be able to locate elements.